# Adding Image Files To Archive

Tags: php, zip

Hi I am having this issue with adding files to archive and it would really help me if someone can help me. Basically all the files that I need to add to archive are in a csv file. I am reading this file using fgetcsv and then trying to loop through each image and add it to archive.

```
        $media_file = "C:/e_files/Exports/Imagery.csv";

        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip->open('C:/e_files/Exports/Feeds/Media.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);


        if (($handle = fopen($media_file, "r")) !== FALSE) 
        {
            $row = 1;

            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) 
            {
                if($row > 1)
                {
                    $image_name = isset($data[1]) ? $data[1] : null;

                    if(!empty($image_name))
                    {
                        $zip->addFile("C:/e_files/Images/$image_name");
                    }
                }

                $row++;
            }
        }

        $zip->close();
```

$media_file is the file that holds all the image names that needs to be added to archive.

C:/e_files/Images is the path in which all the images are stored from which I have to get specific images and add to archive.

But when I run this it is adding the entire C:/e_files/ to zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the second parameter **localname**:

```
$zip->addFile("C:/e_files/Images/$image_name", $image_name);
```

> **localname**
>   If supplied, this is the local name inside the ZIP archive that will override the filename.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php

The filename seems incorrectly derived from the path and being always the same value, it keeps overwriting the previously added file.